# Fixing inconsistent Cypher results in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been getting some strange results with a Neo4j database I made (version 2.1.0-M01). I have a graph with the following relationship:

```
Node[211854]{name : "dst"} <-[:hasrel]- Node[211823]{name : "src"}
```

I've confirmed this relationship using the following query:

```
START m=node(211854) MATCH (m)<-[r]-(n) RETURN m,r,n;
```

which returns a one row result, as expected:

```
| m             | r                 | n
| Node[211854]  | :hasrel[225081]   | Node[211823]
```

The following query returns nothing, however:

```
START n=node(211823) MATCH (m)<-[r]-(n) RETURN m,r,n
```

Any thoughts on what might be happening? I've run these queries with and without indexes on the name properties for the nodes.

EDIT: Fixed typo with initial node number. 
EDIT2: I rebuilt the server and both queries return the results I expect. Perhaps the error was corruption in the first database?

Comment: Nice first question! Thanks for reading the help files first.

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but there is a discrepancy (typo?) in your question: first line of code has node with id `211845`, rest of your question has `211854`.

Comment: WE noticed the exact same issue in one of our Neo4J db's in a clustered environment where each nodes was reporting inconsistent results across the cluster and also the same discrepancy as above on a given node. Restarting the Neo4J servers magically fixed this, but leaves us very concerned about how reliable Neo4J is  in the face of ongoing updates to the db. I thought it was supposed to be transactional.

Answer (score 0):

Using the node id's is not such a good idea, you can use the properties on your node to query them.

For example:

```
MATCH (m)<-[r]-(n {name: "src"}) RETURN m,r,n;
```

Does that query return what you expected?

Comment: My actual database and query use names. Unfortunately, the above query did return what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invert the relationship-direction. As you are looking for incoming relationships for your node 211823, this is not one of them. It's an outgoing relationship.

Please also update your database to the current version: 2.1.2 http://neo4j.org/download

```
START n=node(211823) MATCH (m)-[r]->(n) RETURN m,r,n
```

Perhaps you should give your nodes and relationships more descriptive names, so you spot easier when you inverted a domain concept.

Comment: Are you sure direction is the problem? If path is `(211854)<-[225081]-(211823)` then querying `(211854)<-[r]-(n)` and `(m)<-[r]-(211823)` should both match, no?

Comment: The original poster's query was just fine. WE noticed the exact same issue in one of our Neo4J 2.1.5 db's in a clustered environment where each nodes was reporting inconsistent results across the cluster and also the same discrepancy as above on a given node. Restarting the Neo4J servers magically fixed this, but leaves us very concerned about how reliable Neo4J is in the face of ongoing updates to the db. I thought it was supposed to be transactional.